# How do I push/ create a branch so it assigns to an issue in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have created an issue in GitHub and now I am creating a branch through command line/ vs code, I want the branch to be assigned to the issue - so all commits show up in that Issue.  I know it's possible as I've done it before, I just don't remember how to?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were using before the [vscode-pull-request-github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github) VSCode plugin.

The normal way to assicate a branch to an issue is [described here](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1125) (without VSCode)

> - Create an issue "`My Example Issue`" with id 42
> - See a "`Create Branch for Issue`"-button in the sidebar
> - Click on it and choose where to branch from (e.g. `develop`)
> - define the branch-type according to gitflow (`feature/hotfix`)
> - Create the branch whose name will be inferred from the issue's information `feature/my-example-issue-42` or choose your own name
> - `git fetch` on your local machine and see the new branch
> - switch to it, make the necessary changes described in the issue
> - See the number of commits to this issue in the sidebar
> - Create a pull-request for the branch directly from the sidebar

On GitHub side, an action like [`actions/create-issue-branch`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-issue-branch) can help automate those steps.
Then, once that feature branch is fetched, VSCode can simply switch to it and add/push new commits.